# ANY and ALL when no rows is returned

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle12c

In  [Oracle](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/all-any-some-comparison-conditions-in-sql)

```
If a subquery returns zero rows, 
the condition [operator]ANY[subquery] evaluates to FALSE
the condition [operator]ALL[subquery] evaluates to TRUE
```

On which boolean logic or logical maths is it based ?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing unusual about it - it just implements the mathematical All and Exists operators whose definition is (in layman's terms)

Given a set M and a predicate p, then

```
All m elem M (p) 
<=> each element of M satisfies the predicate p 
<=> there's no element in M that doesn't satisfy p
```

Obviously, this is true for the empty set since it doesn't contain any elements at all.

Given a set M and a predicate p, then

```
Any m elem M (p) 
<=> there exists at least one element of M that satisfies the predicate p 
<=> for all elements of M, the inverse predicate !p is false
```

Obviously, this is false for the empty set since it doesn't contain any elements at all and therefore doesn't have at least one element satisfying the predicate. It also complements the definition of All(m) quite nicely, since

```
All(p) <=> !Any(!p)
```

where `!` denotes the logical inverse NOT.